# Set Indexes correctly for JOIN + LIKE xyz% query

Tags: mysql, indexing, query-optimization, database-performance, query-performance

### EDIT3: Here's the real problem:

It now uses the compound index for `Contact`, but `EXPLAIN` only lists the fkey index for `Address` and neither my multi-column index nor any other single-column index.

```
EXPLAIN EXTENDED SELECT c.*
FROM Contact_Contact c 
LEFT OUTER JOIN Address a ON c.id=a.Contact_id 
WHERE c.deleted<>1 
AND c.external<>1 
AND (
  c.firstName LIKE 'abc%' OR
  c.lastName LIKE 'abc%' OR
  c.Company LIKE 'abc%' OR
  c.label LIKE 'abc%' OR
  a.street LIKE 'abc%' OR
  a.city LIKE 'abc%' OR
  a.region LIKE 'abc%') 
GROUP BY c.id 
ORDER BY c.lastName ASC
LIMIT 30
```

Output:

```
# id, select_type, table, type, possible_keys, key, key_len, ref, rows, filtered, Extra
1, SIMPLE, c, range, myCompositeContactIdx,firstNameIdx,lastNameIdx, myCompositeContactIdx, 1, , 66241, 100.00, Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
1, SIMPLE, a, ref, FK_dc6mn93h87cim4yr8nnijj3fa,myCompositeAddressIdx , FK_dc6mn93h87cim4yr8nnijj3fa, 17, c.id, 1, 100.00, Using where
```

(`FK_dc6mn93h87cim4yr8nnijj3fa` is the fkey on `Address.Contact_id`)

So it looks like it uses the multi-column index on `Contact`, but it doesn't use the multi-column on `Address`, which is defined as:

```
ADD INDEX `myCompositeAddressIdx` USING BTREE (
  `Contact_id` ASC, `street`(255) ASC, `city`(255) ASC, `region`(255) ASC
);
```

Any idea how to make use of `myCompositeAddressIdx`?

---

### EDIT4: Modified query, 30% faster, no index on subquery:

Here's my new query, which takes 250ms (old: 350ms)

```
SELECT c.*
FROM Contact_Contact c
WHERE c.deleted<>1 
AND c.external<>1 
AND (
  c.firstName LIKE 'abc%' OR
  c.lastName LIKE 'abc%' OR
  c.Company LIKE 'abc%' OR
  c.label LIKE 'abc%' OR
  c.id IN (SELECT a.Contact_id FROM Address a WHERE a.street LIKE 'abc%' OR a.city LIKE 'abc%' OR a.region LIKE 'abc%')
  -- ALTERNATIVE:
  -- EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Address a WHERE a.Contact_id=c.id AND (a.street LIKE 'abc%' OR a.city LIKE 'abc%' OR a.region LIKE 'abc%'))
)
GROUP BY c.id 
ORDER BY c.lastName ASC
LIMIT 30
```

(`IN` and `EXISTS` seem to be equally fast)

But `EXPLAIN` still says, that it doesn't use an index on the `Address` table:

```
# id, select_type, table, type, possible_keys, key, key_len, ref, rows, filtered, Extra
1, PRIMARY, c, range, myCompositeContactIdx,firstNameIdx,lastNameIdx, myCompositeContactIdx, 1, , 67138, 100.00, Using where; Using filesort
2, DEPENDENT SUBQUERY, a, index_subquery, FK_dc6mn93h87cim4yr8nnijj3fa,myCompositeAddressIdx,myNEWCompositeAddressIdx, FK_dc6mn93h87cim4yr8nnijj3fa, 17, func, 1, 100.00, Using where
```

With `myNEWCompositeAddressIdx` defined as:

```
ADD INDEX `myNEWCompositeAddressIdx` USING BTREE (
  `street`(255) ASC, `city`(255) ASC, `region`(255) ASC
);
```

---

### Original question:

We have some performance issues with our MySQL DB, the schema looks like:

```
TABLE Contact:
id, firstName, lastName, company

TABLE Address:
id, contact_id, street, city

TABLE ContactGroup:
id, name

TABLE Contact_ContactGroup:
contact_id, contact_group_id
```

(and some more tables, but it's always the same)
(all text fields are VARCHAR(up to 255))

Our query looks like that for input `"abc xyz"`

```
SELECT c.*
FROM Contact c
LEFT JOIN Address a ON a.contact_id = c.id
LEFT JOIN Contact_ContactGroup ccg ON ccg.contact_id = c.id
WHERE
  (
    c.firstName LIKE 'abc%' OR c.firstName LIKE 'xyz%' OR
    c.lastName LIKE 'abc%' OR c.lastName LIKE 'xyz%' OR
    c.company LIKE 'abc%' OR c.company LIKE 'xyz%' OR
    a.street LIKE 'abc%' OR a.street LIKE 'xyz%' OR
    a.city LIKE 'abc%' OR a.city LIKE 'xyz%'
  ) AND
  ccg.contact_group_id IN (1, 2, 3)
GROUP BY
  c.id
ORDER BY
  c.lastName ASC
```

On my dev machine it takes about **280ms** with about 130,000 rows in Contact Table. (Our server needs over 2 seconds for that)

Before we had a `DISTINCT` instead of `GROUP BY`, but it seems it nearly equal performance. And before we also had `LIKE '%abc%'`, but I read that MySQL can't use an index if there's a wild card in front of the search term. The query took about **310ms**.

As you can see, the query did not get significantly faster. I think i did set the indexes wrong. What I set:

```
Contact Index: primary key
id

Contact Index: BTREE
firstName ASC, lastName ASC, company ASC

Address Index: primary key
id

Address Index: BTREE
street ASC, city ASC

Contact_ContactGroup: compound primary key
contact_id, contact_group_id
```

I added the indexes **after** all the data was already in the table. Does MySQL auto index old data? Adding the indexes didn't take more than half a second, though I'm not sure if it really did index the data. And I couldn't find a command to force reindexing a table.

Or is it better to use a single-column index for every column instead of a huge compound index with all columns?

Btw: We're using MySQL 5.5 and InnoDB Tables.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you `:)`

Comment: LIKE '%anything ...' can't use an index at all. Consider using a fulltext index.

Comment: I know, that's why we now only have `anything%`. Corrected the headline, sorry ... Btw: MySQL's `MATCH AGAINST` only supports wildcards at the end, too: `anything*` works, `*anything` won't work.

Comment: I'm sure your WHERE clause isn't what you're intending. You want to put all `OR` expressions in parentheses: `(c.firstName LIKE 'abc%' OR c.firstName LIKE 'xyz%' OR
  c.lastName LIKE 'abc%' OR c.lastName LIKE 'xyz%' OR
  c.company LIKE 'abc%' OR c.company LIKE 'xyz%' OR
  a.street LIKE 'abc%' OR a.street LIKE 'xyz%' OR
  a.city LIKE 'abc%' OR a.city LIKE 'xyz%') AND
  ccg.contact_group_id IN (1, 2, 3)` because AND has higher precedence than OR.

Comment: I just wrote down that query, because I didn't want to copy and paste 50 lines of SQL from our app. And you are right, I missed the parentheses. I'll add that.

Comment: That was more of a sidenote (but the answer of a problem some days ago). Your OR is a performance killer, but you could index all your columns in your WHERE clause. Try a multiple column index in the same order.

Comment: I already have a multi-column index on all those fields in the same order. That's why I created the question `;)`. But is it safe to create the index **after** all the data has been inserted? Or do I somehow have to reindex the table? Can I somehow use `EXPLAIN` to see, if the query actually uses the index?

Comment: I must be blind to have mised that. Using EXPLAIN is ever a good idea.

Comment: It doesn't matter when you create the index. All rows are indexed. Since you reference ccg in your WHERE clause, MySQL treats it as an inner join. With INNER JOINs, MySQL prefers to start with the table with the highest selectivity (fewer rows). Is this ccg? Perhaps. There are a lot of challenges in optimizing this query, and without more information such as number of rows in each table, some idea of the data, and an EXPLAIN result, there's not much we can do but guess. You might start by using UNION instead of OR.

Comment: Okay, here is more information: Contact: 130000 rows, Address: 200000 rows, ContactGroup: 100 rows, (and 2 additional tables with each 200000 rows). The `INNER JOIN` with `ContactGroup` is optional in this query and doesn't always happen. I'll check out the `EXPLAIN` query later and post the result.

Answer (score -1):

Does it depend on system, cause this query took 180 ms on my server,
 i happen to have exact copy of your db schema , also i have indexed earlier prior to PL/SQL procedure development.

```
SELECT c.*
FROM Contact c LEFT JOIN Contact_ContactGroup ccg ON ccg.contact_id = c.id
 LEFT JOIN Address a ON a.contact_id = c.id

WHERE
  c.firstName  LIKE 'abc%xyz%' OR
  c.lastName   LIKE 'abc%xyz%' OR
  c.company   LIKE 'abc%xyz%' OR
  a.street   LIKE 'abc%xyz%' OR
  a.city   LIKE 'abc%xyz%' AND
  ccg.contact_group_id IN (1, 2, 3)
GROUP BY
  c.id
ORDER BY
  c.lastName ASC
```

Comment: Does this really return the same data when using `LIKE 'abc%xyz%'` instead of `LIKE 'abc%' OR LIKE 'xyz%'`. I will try it, but I'm really not sure if that equivalent.

Comment: how may records do you have?

Comment: Tested it, and as expected, it doesn't return the same results. @Sebas  : I've posted the amount of data in the comments above.